# Does this error always indicate a DNS lookup failure?

Tags: ruby, http, dns

I've got an intermittent error in an app where `Net::HTTP` raises `SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)`.

I believe that this means "DNS lookup failure", as in "I can't find the domain for this request". Is that the correct interpretation?

Comment: I think this can happen for a variety of reasons.  `getaddrinfo` is available on [the Socket object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-c-getaddrinfo), so maybe you can experiment with it directly and try to reproduce the error?

Comment: Just thinking out loud, you could try to override it and try to trap the condition that causes the problem.